# Map Image API - Region Resource - request URL too long

Tags: here-api

I want to get an image with an outlined region from the Map Image API Region Resource. I'm getting the coordinates for the region from the Geocoder API and hand these over to the Map Image API.
If the number of coordinates I retrieve from the Geocoder API is relatively low everything is fine. But if there is a large number of coordinates the request URL gets too long for the request.

I already tried to use a POST request but without success and anyway this is not supported.

Is there a way to use the Map Image API Region Resource with a larger amount of coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work by using the Route Resource instead of Region Resource.

The Route Resource is the only one that supports POST requests (and with that supports larger payloads) and has a feature to add polylines. So no filling possible for an region but fine for me.

The funny thing is that the apiKey is not accepted in the payload for whatever reason so I have to send it as an URL parameter... Took me more than an hour to figure that out...

Example:

```py
    map_response = requests.post('https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/route?apiKey='+apiKey, data = {'r':coords, 'lc': 'FFFF0000', 'h':850, 'w':1314})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer but perhaps a workaround would be using a url shortener to reduce the characters.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. 
I think the problem is more on the server side so even if I get the url shorter in the end the server needs to handle the request. 
Or what kind of url shortener do you mean?

Comment: Ah, my assumption was that you are exceeding the character limit for a valid URL. I was referring to something that would work like bitly.com to shorten the length of your URL. But this doesn't fix the server-side problem that you asked about. Can you specify how many coordinates you are interested in passing at a maximum like is it in the order of 100s,Ks, Ms?

Comment: This differs a bit on the response from the first API but there are a few hundred coordinate pairs sometimes.